# Getting Fatal error in cakephp spark-plug

Tags: cakephp

While i was working in cakephp and integrating tumblr api it goes to tumblr site give access permission and when it returns to my site back it gives me the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User::authsomeLogin() is not implemented!' in /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/controllers/components/authsome.php:81 
Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/controllers/components/authsome.php(196): AuthsomeComponent->login('guest') 
 #1 /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/controllers/components/authsome.php(148): AuthsomeComponent->__useGuestAccount() 
 #2 /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/controllers/components/authsome.php(60): AuthsomeComponent->__getActiveUser() 
 #3 /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/config/config.php(71): AuthsomeComponent->get() 
 #4 /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/app_controller.php(11): SparkPlugIt(Object(TumblrController)) in /var/www/vhosts/narolainfotech.com/subdomains/demo/httpdocs/staggr/app/plugins/spark_plug/controllers/components/authsome.php on line 81
```

i tried to search for solution i got something which is not helpful to me and some of the questions even dont have replied any solution.

I got why this error is here. it is just because in callback url i m getting this

http://mysite/tumblr/tumblr_token/?oauth_token=aHOVZIP16c8XJmBQz2ijOW47dgwjpnLanadfDYFQbbBvc7C9Yi&oauth_verifier=c6fvmTsPAdz4TOL57FywrZP0zRoQfBTABiaFsilyUZqjhgiCeZ

Actually this error is here just because when ever session returns to my site from tumblr it is destroyed so how to restore that session.

So pls anybody can help me....
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some of the [solutions listed here](https://github.com/jedt/spark_plug/issues/31)

a potential fix from that page courtesy of [Steinkel](https://github.com/steinkel):

```
public function login($type = 'credentials', $credentials = null) {

        $user = array();
        if ($type != 'guest'){

            $userModel = $this->__getUserModel();

            $args = func_get_args();
            if (!method_exists($userModel, 'authsomeLogin')) {
                throw new Exception(
                $userModel->alias.'::authsomeLogin() is not implemented! in model '
                );
            }

            if (!is_string($type) && is_null($credentials)) {
                $credentials = $type;
                $type = 'credentials';
            }

            $user = $userModel->authsomeLogin($type, $credentials);
        }
        Configure::write($this->settings['configureKey'], $user);
        $this->Session->write($this->settings['sessionKey'], $user);
        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For suggesting solution quick but by using this i get problem in login which is part of spark plug. it doesn't allow me to login to the site. there is any thing else problem in this pls suggest me anything else i cant understand the problem.
Thanks again..

Comment: Yes you are right it works but there is a problem in cakephp right now